# Total Network Monitor plus Autotask

Tags: email, network-monitoring

I apologize if this is not posted in the correct area.  I'm currently using Total Network Monitor to keep a basic eye on my network.  My company is also about to implement Autotask.  Is there a way via the email alerts that TNM sends out to create tickets in Autotask?  Does anyone have any experience or ideas with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Set up Add Ticket Email Service within Autotask](https://www.autotask.net/Help/Content/Extensions/DeveloperTools/ATES/AddTicketEMailService.htm).

If it does not meet your needs, Google revealed the existence of several other Autotask extensions which will also create tickets from email messages.